# insertText not working in UITextView with iOS6?

Tags: uitextview, ios6, xcode4.5

I have developped a litle function to insert text in UITextView and scroll down automatically. It works fine with iOS 5 but since i have updated Xcode to Xcode 4.5 with iOS6, this method no longer works.

Could you help me ?

Here is this method :

```
- (void) insertTextInAPP : (UITextView*) tv : (NSString*) s {
     NSRange range = {[tv.text length], 0};
     [tv setSelectedRange:range];
     [tv insertText:s];
     [tv insertText:@"\n"];
     range.location = [tv.text length];
     [tv scrollRangeToVisible:range];
}
```

And i use this function like this :

```
NSString *newEventString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat : @"Test"];
[self insertTextInAPP:self.outPutTextView: newEventString];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine here (iOS 6, Xcode 5.5). Of course, I needed to change `(UITextView) tv` to `(UITextView*) tv` and `"Test"` to `@"Test"`, but other than that it was alright.

What happens when you try it?

Comment: Yes, i have make some mistakes during my copy/paste. I have edited my post. But it dosen't work with this code. Maybe, this code is OK and the problem is not here? What do you think ? I will try to put this code in another simple project to see if it works..

Comment: I can only tell you that it works fine in my project. What does actually happend when you try it in yours?

Comment: In fact, nothing is printed in the textview.

Comment: Could be your outlets. Could be something else. Without knowing more about the project I can only guess. Have you tried with another project?

Comment: I have resolve the problem by replacing lines [tv insertText:s]; and [tv insertText:@"\n"]; by tv.text = [tv.text stringByAppendingFormat: @"\n %@", s];

Comment: Yes, that will work of course. And you don't need the space after `\n`, unless you actually want to insert a space there (you didn't in the original solution). So just write `[tv.text stringByAppendingFormat: @"\n%@", s]`.